# Swap 1 and 0 in the line

Tags: vim

I have the following line:
`0110101010`

It is necessary to convert 1 to 0, and 0 to 1, i.e. to get:
`1001010101`

Is there any way to do this with vim?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I mean replacing text in a line. The standard `:%s/0/1/1/g` and `:%s/1/0/g` will not help here.
 
>bu yeah, Just negate the binary value
how can this be done?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just using a temporary variable:

`:s/0/x/g | s/1/0/g | s/x/1/g`

The `|` allows multiple commands to be executed in sequence (see `:help :command-bar`).

So we first change `0` to `x` (so we don't end up with all zeros with the 2nd
command), then change `1` to `0`, and finally change the `x` (which were
formerly `0`) to `1`.

Comment: Nice trick, thx. It does what it needs to do.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @Ivan see `:help :s`.

Comment: @Ivan I update the answer to explain.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the matches to apply some logic to it in your replace statement

```
:s/\v(0|1)/\=submatch(0)==0?1:0/g
```

Breaks down to

```
\v(0|1)                   search for either a 0 or 1
\=submatch(0)==0?1:0      if match equals 0 replace with 1, otherwise with 0
```

Look for `:h \=` and `:h submatch` for additional help.

**Edit** <sub>cudo's to BEn C</sub>

alternatively, use some clever arithmetic to shorten the command

```
:s/\v(0|1)/\=1-submatch(0)/g
```

Comment: This is the most concise and elegant answer.

Comment: You can save a few characters using arithmetic with `:s/\v(0|1)/\=1-submatch(0)/g`

Answer (score 3):

How about leveraging common command-line tools?

```
:.!tr 10 01
```

Or a purely programmatic approach?

```
:call getline('.')->tr('01','10')->setline('.')
```

See `:help getline()`, `:help setline()`, `:help tr()`, and `:help :!`.

Comment: On default Windows GVim, `:.!tr` returns error `'tr' is not recognized...` (but it works nicely on Vim in WSL -- thanks!).  The `:call getline...` one works in Windows GVim, and in Vim in WSL.  (Your answers very often open new vistas in Vim for me to explore.  Thanks.)